# How to mock password encoder using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-security, mockito

I'm using Spring security and would like to unit test the password returned by my service. However, as this is encrypted, I'm trying to mock the method that does this encription which is inside the class which extends from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth){
     auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());        
}
```

So I'm trying something like this

```
@Autowired
AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth;


static class PasswordEncoderTest implements PasswordEncoder {
    @Override
    public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
        return charSequence.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
        return charSequence.toString().equals(s);
    }
}

@Test
void testCreateUser() throws Exception {

    UserCreateDto userCreateDto = new UserCreateDto("user", "test", "user@gmail.com", "user@gmail.com", "123456", "basic");
    User userMocked = new User(userId, "user", "test", "user@gmail.com", "user@gmail.com", "123456", "basic");

    PasswordEncoderTest passwordEncoderTest = new PasswordEncoderTest();
    passwordEncoderTest.encode("123456");
    when(auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())).thenReturn(auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoderTest));

    userCreateDto = userCommandService.createUser(userCreateDto);

    assertEquals(userMocked.getPassword(), userCreateDto.getPassword());
}
```

But it fails with `DaoAuthenticationConfigurer cannot be returned by generateToken() generateToken() should return String`

Not sure if the approach is correct and if it is what I may be doing wrong.

Thank you.

*UPDATE*

https://github.com/francislainy/adverts-backend/tree/dev_jwt

Based on my conversation with Plalx, It seems I should be injecting password encoder rather than bycript and have different configurations between the main and test classes. Will try that and get back here with further updates.

Comment: Without seeing the implementation of `createUser` it isn't possible to help, but your `when(...)` does not look as though it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working now. Rather than mocking the hashing, having **two different beans**, one under `Configuration` and the other under `TestConfiguration` did the trick. **The bean for the tests doesn't not have hashing**.

**Config for the main application:**

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**Config for the tests:**

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
       return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance() ;
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
@Import({TestConfig.class})
@WebMvcTest(UserCommandService.class)
class UserCommandServiceTest {

@MockBean
UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private UserCommandService userCommandService;

@MockBean
private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

@MockBean
private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

@Test
void testCreateUser() {

    User userMocked = new User(userId, "user", "test", "user@gmail.com", "123456", "user@gmail.com", "basic");
    UserCreateDto userCreateDto = new UserCreateDto("user", "test", "user@gmail.com", "123456", user@gmail.com", "basic");

    when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(userMocked);

    userCreateDto = userCommandService.createUser(userCreateDto);
    assertEquals(userMocked.getPassword(), userCreateDto.getPassword());
}

}
```

PS: Don't forget to @Import the TestConfig class above the class name.

And finally the Service class

```
@Service
public class UserCommandServiceImpl implements UserCommandService {

private final UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public UserCommandServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@Override
public UserCreateDto createUser(UserCreateDto userCreateDto) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstname(userCreateDto.getFirstname());
    user.setLastname(userCreateDto.getLastname());
    user.setEmail(userCreateDto.getEmail());
    user.setUsername(userCreateDto.getUsername());
    user.setPassword(userCreateDto.getPassword());

    user = userRepository.save(user);

    return new UserCreateDto(user.getId(), user.getFirstname(), user.getLastname(), user.getUsername(), passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()), user.getEmail(), user.getRole());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean an integration test... I can't really try it, but I think you could configure the `PasswordEncoder` as a `@Bean` and then override the bean configuration to use a non-encoding `PasswordEncoder`.

e.g.

```
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth){
     
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);        
    }
}
```

And then in your test you'd have a bean definition such as:

```java
@Bean public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new PasswordEncoderTest();
}
```

There might be some tweaking, but that's the idea.

---

Note that if the only reason for using `configure` is to override the collaborators then you can just remove the `configure` block and rather define the `PasswordEncoder` & `UserDetailsService` beans.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. What would change on this line though?  ```when(auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())).thenReturn(auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoderTest));```

Comment: And I get this error ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Test classes cannot include @Bean methods``` when I add the bean to the test class.

Comment: You may have to define the bean on another class an use `@SpringBootTest(classes = { TestConfig.class })`. I think the mocking line (when call) could then be removed entirely, since you'd use the standard `UserDetailsService` which will have been configured with the fake `TestPasswordEncoder`.

Comment: Thank you. I've created the class for the bean and removed the when line but I now get ```Invalid bean definition with name 'passwordEncoder'```.

Comment: Is there further info as to why the definition is invalid? Oh try annotating the `TestConfig` class with `@TestConfiguration`.

Comment: I needed to allow bean overriding on the application file and that ran now. However, the comparison still fails because of the hashing.

Comment: assertEquals(userMocked.getPassword(), userCreateDto.getPassword()); The dto is hashed so there should be a matter of hashing userMocked or another entity that holds the password.

Comment: There's certainly something that's up with the configuration. Can you confirm your custom `TestPasswordEncoder#encode` method gets called? Also you could put a println or breakpoint in the auth configure to make sure it's calling `auth.passwordEncoder` with the expected `TestPasswordEncoder` instance.

Comment: https://github.com/francislainy/adverts-backend/tree/dev_jwt This is my project as it is now.

Comment: Ok yeah see in the `MyWebSecurity` class you call `auth.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())`. This is wrong because it's not using the resolved bean but rather calling the method directly. If you look at my example you will see that I inject the `PasswordEncoder` instance using `@Autowired` in a field and then use that field to configure `auth`. I'm not sure if you can use `@Autowired` for a bean declared in the same class, but the idea is to get the value resolved from the IoC.

Comment: I'm surprised `NoOpPasswordEncoder` would actually encode anything though because the documentation says it doesn't.

Comment: I've done the changes here to use the autowired field but I'm afraid the result is the same.

Comment: So you've changed `auth.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())` to `auth.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)` ? Can you confirm you configure the expected instance when `configure` is called?

Comment: Yes, I've done that. Let me put a break point here.

Comment: The method inside test config doesn't seem to be called.

Comment: Hum ok, however I think I found another issue in your code, look at your  UserCommandServiceImpl, you inject BCrypt encoder rather tahn PasswordEncoder.

Comment: hmm, okay, yes, that's where the hashing was coming from them. So I guess the question is how to mock BCrypt instead..

Comment: Well you dont, you inject `PasswordEncoder` into `UserCommandServiceImpl` instead of asking for bcrypt. Then you configure your application with bcrypt encoder in the `MySecurityConfig` and use the `NoOpEncoder` in the test config. So basically the `@Bean` definition of `PasswordEncoder` in `MySecurityConfig` will return an instance of `BCryptPasswordEncoder` and the bean definition in the `TestConfig` will return `NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance()`.

Comment: Cool, thank you very much. It makes sense. I need to leave now but I'll get back to it during the day and hopefully I'll be able to implement that. I'll need to check why the test configuration was not being called and then will change the implementation between it and the main config.

Comment: @plalx if the password encoder is defined as a bean you dont need to override configure, same goes if you define the userdetailsservice as a bean, no need to build manually. Spring Security will inject them into the framework automatically. I dont understand why people always insist on overriding the config when it is completly unecassary.

Comment: It's working now. Having two different beans one under Configuration and other under TestConfiguration did the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Wasn't sure if there was a reason for the `configure` block or not in the original code so I just sticked to it.

Comment: I've just noticed it that with these changes this now fails ```authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));``` giving me Bad Credentials error (due to the hashing on the password), so the retrieval for the jwt token is no longer working. Looking into it.

Comment: Maybe when I have the user details retrieved directly from the db rather than hardcoded with the foo credentials that will fix it as the saved password will have the hashing.